# Dotenv module not existing in Dockercontainer

Tags: dockerfile, dotenv

I want to build a Docker image that will run the text-generation-webui on a remote Linux server. Dotenv is required for activating some extensions which I need to use to generate audio files, but when I try to activate them I get the following error:

```
2023-08-19 09:39:03 ERROR:Failed to load the extension "bark_tts".
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/app/modules/extensions.py", line 35, in load_extensions
     exec(f"import extensions.{name}.script")
   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
   File "/app/extensions/bark_tts/script.py", line 11, in <module>
     from dotenv import load_dotenv
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dotenv'
```

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the dotenv package:

```
pip uninstall dotenv
WARNING: Skipping dotenv as it is not installed.

pip uninstall python-dotenv
Found existing installation: python-dotenv 0.19.2
Not uninstalling python-dotenv at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages, outside environment /usr
Can't uninstall 'python-dotenv'. No files were found to uninstall.
```

I thought adding python-dotenv to the Dockerfile should fix the problem but it is still not working. This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM nvidia/cuda:11.8.0-devel-ubuntu22.04 as builder

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y git vim build-essential python3-dev python3-venv && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN git clone https://github.com/oobabooga/GPTQ-for-LLaMa /build

WORKDIR /build

RUN python3 -m venv /build/venv
RUN . /build/venv/bin/activate && \
    pip3 install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel && \
    pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio && \
    pip3 install -r requirements.txt && \
    pip3 install -U python-dotenv

# https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus
# for a rtx 2060: ARG TORCH_CUDA_ARCH_LIST="7.5"
ARG TORCH_CUDA_ARCH_LIST="${TORCH_CUDA_ARCH_LIST:-3.5;5.0;6.0;6.1;7.0;7.5;8.0;8.6+PTX}"
RUN . /build/venv/bin/activate && \
    python3 setup_cuda.py bdist_wheel -d .

FROM nvidia/cuda:11.8.0-runtime-ubuntu22.04

LABEL maintainer="Your Name <your.email@example.com>"
LABEL description="Docker image for GPTQ-for-LLaMa and Text Generation WebUI"

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y python3-dev libportaudio2 libasound-dev git python3 python3-pip make g++>    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.cache/pip pip3 install virtualenv
RUN mkdir /app

WORKDIR /app

ARG WEBUI_VERSION
RUN test -n "${WEBUI_VERSION}" && git reset --hard ${WEBUI_VERSION} || echo "Using provided webui source"

RUN virtualenv /app/venv
RUN . /app/venv/bin/activate && \
    pip3 install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel && \
    pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio

COPY --from=builder /build /app/repositories/GPTQ-for-LLaMa
RUN . /app/venv/bin/activate && \
    pip3 install /app/repositories/GPTQ-for-LLaMa/*.whl

COPY extensions/api/requirements.txt /app/extensions/api/requirements.txt
COPY extensions/elevenlabs_tts/requirements.txt /app/extensions/elevenlabs_tts/requirements.txt
COPY extensions/google_translate/requirements.txt /app/extensions/google_translate/requirements.txt
COPY extensions/silero_tts/requirements.txt /app/extensions/silero_tts/requirements.txt
COPY extensions/whisper_stt/requirements.txt /app/extensions/whisper_stt/requirements.txt
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.cache/pip . /app/venv/bin/activate && cd extensions/api && pip3 install -r requirements.txt
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.cache/pip . /app/venv/bin/activate && cd extensions/elevenlabs_tts && pip3 install -r requirements.txt
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.cache/pip . /app/venv/bin/activate && cd extensions/google_translate && pip3 install -r requirements.txt
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.cache/pip . /app/venv/bin/activate && cd extensions/silero_tts && pip3 install -r requirements.txt
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.cache/pip . /app/venv/bin/activate && cd extensions/whisper_stt && pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN . /app/venv/bin/activate && \
    pip3 install -r requirements.txt

RUN cp /app/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/bitsandbytes/libbitsandbytes_cuda118.so /app/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/bitsandbytes/libbitsandbytes_cpu.so

COPY . /app/
ENV CLI_ARGS=""
CMD . /app/venv/bin/activate && python3 server.py ${CLI_ARGS}
```

Answer (score 0):

I included python-dotenv in the requirements.txt of the Dockercontainer.